# Why is my container no scrolling as i click on the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to do a horizontal slider with buttons. So i have 6 cards and 6 dot buttons. As i click for example in the second button with id of 1 it should slide to the second image. But fore some reason the scroll event is not working.

This is my css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 810px){
    .fake-magicwall ul{
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-x: auto;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;

    }

    .dot{
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
      
    }
}
```

And this is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Work.css'
import Cta from '../atoms/Cta'
import Headphone from '../assets/images/headphones3.png'
import Calendar from '../assets/images/calendar.png'
import DevConnector from '../assets/images/dev.png'
import Bulls from '../assets/images/bulls2.png'
import Expenses from '../assets/images/reactExpenses.png'
import SixFlags from '../assets/images/sixflags.png'
import useDots from '../hooks/useDots';


const images = [Calendar, Headphone, SixFlags, DevConnector, Bulls, Expenses];

const Work = () => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useDots(images.length);

    function handleDotClick(index) {
        console.log("Clicked dot with index:", index);
      
        setActiveIndex(index);
      
        const targetCard = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${index}"]`);
        console.log("Target card:", targetCard);
      
        if (targetCard) {
          const magicWall = document.getElementById('home-magicwall');
          console.log("Magic wall:", magicWall);
          console.log("Target card offsetLeft:", targetCard.offsetLeft);
          console.log("Magic wall offsetLeft:", magicWall.offsetLeft);
      
          magicWall.scroll({
            left: targetCard.offsetLeft - magicWall.offsetLeft,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      }
      
      
      
  
    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <section id="section-work">
          <div id="header">
            <h2>My Work</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="text-zone-2">
            <div>
              <p>
                A small gallery of recent projects chosen by me. I've done them all together with amazing people from
                companies around the globe. It's only a drop in the ocean compared to the entire list. Interested to see
                some more? Visit my work page.
                <br />
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-container">
              <Cta className="btn" link="https://github.com/mateoghidini1998" content="See More" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="fake-big-2">Work</div>
        </section>
        <div className="dots">
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                className={`dot ${index === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => handleDotClick(index)}
              ></button>
            ))}
          </div>
        <div id="home-magicwall" className="fake-magicwall">
          <ul>
            {images.map((image, index) => (
              <li key={index} className={`magic-wall_item ${index === activeIndex ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                <img src={image} alt="image" />
                <div className="hover-content"></div>
                <a href="/" className="colorbox" data-id={index}></a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
  
          
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
export default Work;
```

This is my custom hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useDots(images) {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  return [activeIndex, setActiveIndex];
}

export default useDots;
```

I did some console log and the index of the dot i am clicking is correct.
The data-id on the `<a>` tags is correct.
I also get `Target card offsetLeft: 133`
and `Magic wall offsetLeft: 0` Every time i click in a button

Any reason why it is not scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the `overflow-x: auto` to the `ul` element inside of the `home-magicwall` div and not the `home-magicwall` div itself so that technically isn't scrollable. Try the `ul` instead:

```
        if (targetCard) {
          const magicWall = document.querySelector('.home-magicwall ul');
          console.log("Magic wall:", magicWall);
          console.log("Target card offsetLeft:", targetCard.offsetLeft);
          console.log("Magic wall offsetLeft:", magicWall.offsetLeft);
      
          magicWall.scroll({
            left: targetCard.offsetLeft - magicWall.offsetLeft,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
```